# Can i include alloyUI lib and also keeps the jQuery lib?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, plugins

Sorry about the lame question, but here we go:

Can I include the AlloyUI lib on my project and keep the jQuery lib ?
I mean, i already have some functions with jQuery, but i also would like to use the alloyUI components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use as many libs as you want, buy you have to be carefull with their components, if they have the same "tags" you will have a problem with conflicts.